# Join by ids in a list is taking forever

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Is there some way to improve the running time of this query. It is taking forever.
I have a document table which has a column named content as jsonb. Both media and document has columns id::int and application_instance::int. I want to check if any of the contained media-ids has a different application_instance.id than the media-ids in document.content.

- document.content can contain jsonb in any shape or form.
- media has ~30000 rows
- documents has ~9500 rows

Code:

```
SELECT doc.application_instance_id = m.application_instance_id as isEqual,
       doc.id,
       doc.application_instance_id,
       m.id,
       m.application_instance_id,
       jsonb_path_query_array(content, '$.**.mediaId') as array_of_media_ids
FROM document doc
INNER JOIN media m on m.id in
(
SELECT nullif(list_of_media_ids, 'null')::int FROM jsonb_path_query(doc.content, '$.**.mediaId') as list_of_media_ids
 ) ORDER BY isEqual
;
```

Comment: Please indicate what indexes have been defined on the tables and include output from `EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE`

Comment: Could you please share the DDL for all tables and indexes involved, in plain text as an update to your question. And the results from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) for this SQL statement, also in plain text.

Comment: That query will always be slow. You painted yourself in a corner by using JSON for this. Try to extract `mediaId` to a regular table column.

Comment: I'm sure there is some way to speed it up, but without sample data I doubt anyone is going to bother trying to guess what the structure of your JSON documents is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the query to make it run in ~250 ms instead of >1 hour.

```
SELECT m.id, 
       m.application_instance_id, 
       doc_media_ids.application_instance_id 
from media m
JOIN (
SELECT 
    doc.id, 
    doc.application_instance_id, 
    (nullif(jsonb_path_query(doc.content, '$.**.mediaId'), 'null')::int) as doc_media 
    FROM  document doc) as doc_media_ids
ON m.id = doc_media_ids.doc_media and 
   m.application_instance_id != doc_media_ids.application_instance_id
```

Comment: I really don't understand why this query takes ~250 ms while the query in the original question takes 1.5 hours.